# Get Months between two Date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table `AreaValues` with columns `ID`, `Name`, `Value`, `startDate`, `EndDate`.

I need to view a report that select the values of every month with month name or number

Example: this is my table `AreaValues`:

```
ID  Name   Value  StartDate    EndDate 
-------------------------------------------
1   Test   200    05-06-2012   07-08-2016
```

I need report get the value using SQL Server Reporting Services or query or any way:

```
month value = (200 / count of months from startdate to end date)

ID   Name    Value    year2012           year2013       year2014      year2015       year2016
1    test     200     6,7,8,9,10,11,12   1,2,3,....12   1,2,3,....12  1,2,3,....12   1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

and do that for every record in the table

Please, I need help

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It looks like you want a dynamic number of columns based on the difference between the earliest StartDate and last EndDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Solved 
I used a Loop in SQl that get all months between two dates 
Then 
Create report with **Matrix** get the months above and ID left